# Data ranged subscribe strange behavior

Tags: swift

I was playing with swift's `Data` in the following a small code:

```swift
var d = Data(count: 10)
d[5] = 3
let d2 = d[5..<8]
print("\(d2[0])")
```

To my surprise, this code throws exception on `print()` while the following code does not:

```swift
var d = Data(count: 10)
d[5] = 3
let d2 = d.subdata(in: 5..<8)
print("\(d2[0])")
```

I somehow understand why this happens, but I don't get why this is designed like this. When I use `subdata()` I get a whole copy of range, so indexing is valid from `0`. But when I use range subscribe `[]`, I get access to the requested range while indexing is the same as before. So in my first example `d2[5]` is `3`.

But I wonder why it is designed like this? I don't want to make a copy of my data by using `subdata()` method. I just wanted to access a portion of my data with better indexing.

This is especially creates unexpected behaviors if you pass it to a function. For example, following code creates unexpected results and exceptions and you may not find out easily why:

```swift
func testit(idata: Data) {
    if idata.count > 0 {
        print("\(idata.count)")
        print("\(idata[0])")
    }
}
//...
var d = Data(count: 10)
d[5] = 3
let d2 = d[5..<8]
testit(idata: d2)
```

This code is really strange. Because if you debug your code, you see that `print("\(idata.count)")` prints `3` as size of `idata` which is correct, but accessing it with `idata[0]` creates exception.

Is there any reason for this design? I was expecting that I could access resulting `Data` from subscribe starting index 0 while it is not true. Can I do this without using `subdata()` which creates copy of data or using additional arguments to pass base of data slice?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/slice: *“Indices of a slice can be used interchangeably with indices of the base collection.”* – Replace `idata[0]` by `idata[idata.startIndex]` or `idata.first` for a safe version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`d[5..<8]` returns `Data.Slice` – which happens to be `Data`. Generally, slices share the indices with their base collection, as documented in [`Slice`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/slice).

One possible reason for this design decision is that it guarantees that subscripting a slice is a O(1) operation (adding an *offset* for accessing the base collection is not necessarily O(1), e.g. not for strings.)

It is also convenient, as in this example to locate the text after the second occurrence of a character in a string:

```
let string = "abcdefgabcdefg"

// Find first occurrence of "d":
if let r1 = string.range(of: "d") {
    // Find second occurrence of "d":
    if let r2 = string[r1.upperBound...].range(of: "d") {
        print(string[r2.upperBound...]) // efg
    }
}
```

As a consequence, you must never assume that the indices of a collection are zero-based (unless documented, as for [`Array.startIndex`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1541237-startindex)). Use `startIndex` to get the first index, or `first` to get the first element.