# Why does Data not reset its index after popFirst, and can I change that?

Tags: swift

So, I'm doing some development in Swift, and I'm doing a small refactor to improve the internal logistics. I'm changing a class that was handling `[UInt8]` variables to handle `Data` objects instead. The problem: say I do something like this...

```
var data = Data()
var buffer = < an incoming Data object >
buffer.removeFirst()
buffer.removeFirst()
data = buffer[0..<32]
```

I get a hard EXC_BREAKPOINT error and the debugger tells me `data` is represented by a `slice` with range e.g. `2..<40` right now. I didn't have this problem with `[UInt8]`, and it looks like `.removeFirst()` doesn't reset `Data`'s index like it does for `[UInt8]`.

I can get around this by, for example, doing `buffer = Data(buffer)` to get a fresh index every time, but I don't feel great about that. Neither do I want to allow this buffer's index to increment forever, as it's going to handle an indefinite stream of incoming data.

With my limited Google-fu, I was unable to find confirmation of this difference, nevermind an explanation. I'd love to understand why `.removeFirst` displays this difference in behaviour. I'd also love any tips, tricks etc that might come up. Originally, I was converting my incoming `Data` to `[UInt8]` and then back into `Data`, and I'm hoping to get rid of those seemingly excessive conversions.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56618001/1187415.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR ! I failed to find that.