# Why are Data.endIndex and Data.count different?

Tags: swift

```
let str = "This is a swift bug"
let data = Data(str.utf8)
print("data size = ", data.endIndex, data.count)

let trimmed = data[2..<data.endIndex]
print("trimmed size = ", trimmed.endIndex, trimmed.count)
```

The result is

```
data size =  19 19
trimmed size =  19 17
```

According to the Apple doc about `endIndex`:

```
This is the “one-past-the-end” position, and will always be equal to the count.
```

Is it a bug? or I'm missing something?

Comment: Don't use subscript. You should always use Data's `subdata` method `data.subdata(in: 2..<data.endIndex)`. It will also avoid unaligned data.

Comment: I don't agree one should "always" use `subdata`. Using pointer to the same memory without copying is totally valid use case to save memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should open an Apple Feedback for the documentation of `Data.endIndex`. It's incorrect.

The startIndex of Data is not promised to be zero, and this is an example of when it isn't. Using the Int subscript on Data is unfortunately very dangerous unless you know precisely how the Data was constructed (and specifically that it has a zero index).

Data uniquely mixes two facts that make it tricky to use correctly:

- It is its own Slice
- Its Index is Int

For some discussion of this, and suggested patterns, see [Data.popFirst(), removeFirst() adjust indices](https://forums.swift.org/t/data-popfirst-removefirst-adjust-indices/35965/9). Also see [Data ranged subscribe strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618001/data-ranged-subscribe-strange-behavior) for another version of this question.

Answer (score 5):

When you use an expression like `array[2..<array.endIndex]` you are creating a *slice*. A slice is a sort of window onto an array (or something similar to an array). Its `startIndex` is not necessarily `0` and its `endIndex` is not necessarily one after the last index of the original.

Example:

```
let arr = Array(1...10)
print(arr.startIndex) // 0
print(arr.endIndex) // 10
let slice = arr[2...4]
print(slice.startIndex) // 2
print(slice.endIndex) // 5
print(slice.count) // 3
```

You see how this works? The slice has its own logic. Its size (count) is the size of the slice, but its index numbers come from the original array, because the slice is nothing but a pointer into a section of the original array. It has no independent existence; it is just a way of seeing, as it were.

An important consequence is that `slice[0]` will crash: the first available index of `slice` is 2, as we have already been told. This is why it is crucial to know whether you're dealing with an original array or a slice.

However, at least you have reason to know that this issue might exist, because `slice` has a special type — `Array<Int>.SubSequence`, meaning an ArraySlice. But the fact that you are encountering this by way of Data makes it more tricky, because `trimmed` is typed as a Data, not as a DataSlice! It *is* in fact a `Data.SubSequence`, but you have no simple way of finding that out! That's because `Data.SubSequence` is typealiased to Data itself. This is to be regarded as a flaw in the Data implementation.

Nevertheless, it is exactly the same phenomenon. These answers should look strangely familiar:

```
let str = "This is a swift bug"
let data = Data(str.utf8)
let trimmed = data[2...4]
print(trimmed.startIndex) // 2
print(trimmed.endIndex) // 5
print(trimmed.count) // 3
```

The best way to solve this is Don't Do That. To take a subrange of a Data as a true Data, use `subdata`:

```
let trimmed2 = data.subdata(in: 2..<5)
print(trimmed2.startIndex) // 0, and so on; it's an independent copy
```

Comment: @aheze Actually I'm just saying what Rob Napier said. He said it more compactly! The core of the issue is summed up in his phrase "Data is its own Slice". I'm just explaining what that means. :)